# Moving ESXI host to Internal VM network

Tags: vmware, esxi, vcenter, vdi

Is there a way to move the ESXI host to a network that was internally created? For example, I have a forest on that host with the DC acting as a router between an internal network (with all the VMs) and the internet. This is so when I tinker(learn) with the setup the effects stay behind the router. Since the vcenter is in that internal network, it can't manage the ESXI host. Is there some setting I'm missing to change which network it listens to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Someone came down from upstairs and randomly knew how: Create a new management network on the internal segment and delete the one on the external segment. Picked up my internal DHCP and life is good!